# query custom post type by advanced custome field value

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

i used advanced custom field to make 3 radio buttons

and every post should have one of the three values

1- first home 
2- second home 
3- offices

```
<?php
    $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'development',
            'order'    => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            'orderby'    => 'date',//possible values id,url,name,target,description,owner,rating,rel,notes,rss,length,rand,

            'meta_query' => array (

                'key' => 'life_style',
                'value' => 'firsthome'

            )



        );
        query_posts( $args );
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

i used this code and it's not working

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use

```
'life_style' => 'firsthome',
```

instead of

```
'meta_query' => array (

    'key' => 'life_style',
    'value' => 'firsthome'

)
```

meta_query is not in class reference of [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)